# imshow() in OpenCV doesn't work for cv::Mat type CV_32F?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I have a float array

```
float* data; // stores pixel gray color 
cv::Mat img(h,w,CV_32F,data);
cv::namedWindow("Display window");
cv::imshow( "Display window", img );
```

Then what I get is :

[image]

I searched for many resources but couldnt find out. I doubt it's the problem of the type but I compared with the definition and I think it's ok.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: what did you expect it to look like? What colour is 3.40282347E+38 ? Or -3.40282347E+38  for that matter. Try converting the range of floats you are interested in into 8but

Comment: If the type is float, the values must be between 0 and 1 to be displayed correctly... didn't you read the doc?

Comment: pixel <=0 is rendered as black, pixel >=1 is rendered as white 0 <pixel<1 is rendered as a gray value. So probably you have to scale your image. Try cv::imshow( "Display window", img*(1.0/255.0) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is a single channel one, then you convert it to `CV_8U` by:

```
float* data; // stores pixel gray color 

cv::Mat img(h,w,CV_32F,data), 8u_image;

img.convertTo(8u_image,CV_8U);

cv::namedWindow("Display window");

cv::imshow( "Display window", 8u_image );
```

Comment: But my question is CV_32F is also single channel, why it cannot show image?

Comment: any pixel above a value of 255 will be displayed as white. Hence you have a white screen.